# could not obtain extracted text error on iterate an array

Tags: android

I'm beginner in Android and maybe my question be so simple.

I have defined a simple **array** and then push some strings from DB. like this :

```
db=new mydatabasehandlerTile(this);
mylist = new ArrayList<String>();
mylist=db.getfavoriteslist();

for(int i=1;i<=mylist.size();i++) {               
  Toast.makeText(this,String.valueOf(mylist.get(i)), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();              
}
```

As you can see I want to show each of array string item in Toast. but whenever I run my app I got this error and app is crashed :

```
onStartInput event aborted: com.touchtype.keyboard.h.p: could not obtain extracted text (class com.touchtype.keyboard.h.p)
```

I do not know what is problem. can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious error that I see in your code is that you don't take in account that the index of the list is zero based, so change to this:

```
for(int i=0;i<mylist.size();i++) {               
  Toast.makeText(this,String.valueOf(mylist.get(i)), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();              
}
```